# How do I select record from mysql database based on the longest 'string' in one filed when grouping?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, string, select

This is my table:

```
ID    Title    Content    Cluster
1       a       abc         1
2       b       abcde       1
3       c       abcde       1
4       d       abc         2
5       e       abcdef      2
```

I want to select record based on the longest 'string' in field content and group by cluster. how can i do that.

the desired results:

```
ID    Title    Content    Cluster
3       c       abcde       1
5       e       abcdef      2
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using self join, you can find out the all the rows with max length in each cluster:

```
select a.*
from my_table a
left join my_table b
on a.cluster = b.cluster
and length(a.content) < length(b.content)
where b.cluster is null;
```

#### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5759/1)

Another way is using group by in subquery:

```
select a.*
from my_table a
inner join (
    select cluster, max(length(content)) len
    from my_table
    group by cluster
) b on a.cluster = b.cluster and length(a.content) = b.len;
```

Also, if content contains Unicode characters, then use `char_length` instead of `length` function.

#### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5759/2)

#### EDIT:

For clearing ties on length, you can get the row with highest id (or lowest based on your needs):

```
select a.*
from cluster_sosial a
left join cluster_sosial b
on a.cluster = b.cluster
and (
    length(a.content) < length(b.content)
    or (length(a.content) = length(b.content) and a.cluster_sosial_id < b.cluster_sosial_id)
)
where b.cluster is null;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/OFJ7380)

Using correlated subquery

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    cluster_sosial a
WHERE
    cluster_sosial_id = (SELECT 
            cluster_sosial_id
        FROM
            cluster_sosial B
        WHERE
            a.Cluster = b.Cluster
        ORDER BY LENGTH(content) DESC , cluster_sosial_id DESC
        LIMIT 1)
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/VMCYY99768)

Comment: this sql also displays all the records

Comment: the problem is when the content has the same length, for example if there are two records  and the length of field content of that two records is the same, the result will display all that two records. what i want is just one record displayed for each cluster

Comment: @MuhammadHaryadiFutra - Try my latest edit. Added a demo as well

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM   Yourtable a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   Yourtable B
               WHERE  a.Cluster = b.Cluster
               HAVING Max(Len(b.Content)) = Len(a.Content))
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM   yourtable a
WHERE  Content = (SELECT content
                    FROM   yourtable  B
                    WHERE  a.Cluster = b.Cluster
                    ORDER  BY Len(content) DESC Limit 1)
```

Comment: this sql displays all the records